# Detecting if account selected via AccountPicker is still valid without GET_ACCOUNTS permission

Tags: android, google-oauth, android-permissions

In my app I use `AccountPicker.newChooseAccountIntent()` to get the user to select an account and then use `GoogleAuthUtil.getToken()` to obtain an auth token for that account.

This is all done without requiring the `GET_ACCOUNTS` permission on Marshmallow.

The problem I have after moving to API 23 is that I cannot detect when the selected account is no longer valid because `AccountManager.getAccountsByType()` returns an empty list for google accounts as I do not have the `GET_ACCOUNTS` permission.

It is quite annoying to have the ability to select and authenticate using a google account without `GET_ACCOUNTS`, but lack the ability to detect when the account is no longer valid.

Does anyone know how to detect when the account is no longer valid?

Comment: you have get runtime permission in API 23 and greater

Comment: It is annoying that you can get the user to select an account and get an authentication token without having the `GET_ACCOUNTS` permission, but you cannot verify that the account still exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `GoogleAuthUtil.getToken()` at all, nor `AccountPicker.newChooseAccountIntent()`. As per the [Improving the Security and User Experience of your Google Sign In Implementation blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/05/improving-security-and-user-experience.html), `getToken()` is vulnerable to a token substitution attack.

You should follow the [migration guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/migration-guide#migrate_to_the_id_token_flow) to use [Google Sign In](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/) and the [requestIdToken() flow](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth). This allows you to 1) know what account is signed in 2) know when that account is no longer valid and 3) still get tokens needed to authenticate with Google services.

Comment: I have scanned the pages you referenced and they seem to provide a (better) alternative to what I already have. One thing that I still don't understand is how to verify that the account selected is still OK.

I use the google token to get a session id on my server. The session is used for as long as the auth token is valid.  I cannot see how to detect this in the app with the new flow.

Comment: When using the Google Sign-In APIs, you'll never be connected to an invalid account - you'll just get a notice of sign in failure (where you can ask the user to sign in with a new account, etc)

Comment: Sorry, I edited my original comment before noticing your response.

I use the google token to get a session id on my server. The session is used for as long as the auth token is valid. I cannot see how to detect this in the app with the new flow.

Comment: I just finished scanning the [blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.au/2016/05/improving-security-and-user-experience.html). Right down the bottom it seems to be describing what I am doing as an exception to the new flow.
_In general, you should NOT use GoogleAuthUtil.getToken, unless you are making REST API call on Android client._

Comment: Hmm... I might have misunderstood what the blog post meant by _REST API call on Android client_.

I just finished migrating my Google Drive code away from the web API because it also required `GET_ACCOUNTS`. The results were quite disappointing. The lag on writing back to Google Drive is terrible. With the web API you can update Google Drive immediately.

Comment: Sorry for the spammy messages, but can the `GoogleSignInApi.silentSignIn()` [method](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInApi.html#silentSignIn(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient)) be used to verify that the account selected in a previous execution of the app is still valid?

Comment: I have mostly converted my app to use the new Google Sign In process and have deleted a lot of code. This is a way better approach.